# Upload Image from Iphone to WCF Service : stream or REST?

Tags: iphone, wcf, image, upload

I google a lot this question and I'm a bit confused.
I need to upload an image from Iphone to a WCF service.
I've already a working WCF which receive an image in 'stream' mode.
But I read somewhere a must use a REST WCF in order to work whit iphone.
What should I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading a image "as is" from the iPhone, I imagine that you're already using the REST mode in WCF to do that. If your service endpoint uses the `webHttpBinding` and has a `webHttpBehavior` added to it, then you're already in the "WCF REST" realm (the official name is "WCF WebHTTP Endpoints", but it's more known as WCF REST endpoints).

Even if you're not using WCF REST, if what you have is working for you, then you're fine.